# Seeking to understand how this error "Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException" comes about

Tags: laravel, validation

I've got the following code and it's working just well as expected when uploading images but I noticed when I try to upload a video I get the error `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException`. I was expecting to get an error on browser "The make field should be an image" just as the other validations are working. Could someone kindly explain what's happening here, shouldn't validation stop immediately the uploaded file is found to be not an image? Is the validation checking for size first and yet that's not what I've provided in validation?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'condition' => 'required',
            'make' => 'required | alpha',
            'model' => 'required | alpha_dash',
            'filenames' => 'required | image',
            'filenames.*' => 'image',

         ]);


        $files = [];
        if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().rand(1,100).'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(public_path('files'), $name);
                $files[] = $name;
            }
        }

        $vehicle = new Vehicle;
        $vehicle->condition = $request->condition;
        $vehicle->make = $request->make;
        $vehicle->model = $request->model;
        $vehicle->filenames= $files;
        $vehicle->save();

       return redirect(route('vehicles.create'))->with('flash', 'Vehicle Post Created
       Successfully');}
```

Comment: that isn't validation that is a middleware, `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize`, that is checking that and throwing an exception because the upload was too large, so this is before you even get to validation

Comment: That makes sense, how do I fix that?

Comment: you could try to increase the `post_max_size` for the php configuration